# ¿Cómo quitar negritas de una tabla de contenido y de los nombres de la figuras en LaTex?

Tags: latex

En mi texis de grado me exigen un formato especifico, en este las tablas de contenido no tienen negritas, pero al usar el comando de LaTex me inserta con negritas, ¿qué debo hacer para quitarle las negritas?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De igual forma las negritas en los nombres de las figuras.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añadiendo a tu pregunta el .tex que corresponde a eso que preguntas, será más fácil responderte

Comment: Esas negrillas están ahi porque algún comando las puso. El formato que muestras no es el estándar latex, de donde se deduce que estás usando alguna plantilla y paquetes "personalizados" que son los que dan ese aspecto. Obviamente sin acceso al fuente de tus documentos es imposible saber en qué parte del "setup" se están añadiendo esas negrillas. ¿Por qué no creas en Overleaf un documento que use tu mismo setup y que muestre ese problema, pero sin incluir todo el texto de tu tesis? Después puedes compartir el enlace a overleaf para que investiguemos

Answer (score 0):

Para los títulos puede probar con

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

% indented subsection (in toc)
\titlecontents{chapter}
[0.0cm]             % left margin
{\vspace{1cm}}                  % above code
{%                  % numbered format
{{\scshape\large Chapter} \thecontentslabel---}%
}%
{}         % unnumbered format
{}         % filler-page-format, e.g dots
```

Para las figuras con:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\footnotesize Figura}
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
\vskip\abovecaptionskip
\sbox\@tempboxa{\footnotesize #1. #2}%
\ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
\begin{center}
    \footnotesize #1. #2\par
\end{center}
\else
\global \@minipagefalse
\hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
\fi
\vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother
```